# Angular: Return data only once several promises are fulfilled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, service

I want to return data from a Service function and inject it into a controller via the routeProvider, but only once the data has been fully loaded.

app.js:

```
    .when('/sources', {
        templateUrl: 'views/app/source/inventory.html',
        controller: 'InventoryCtrl',
        pageTitle: 'Data Inventory',
        resolve: {
            orders: function (OrderService) {
                return OrderService.getOrders();
            },
            sources: function (SourceService) {
                return SourceService.getSources();
            }
        }
    })
```

SourceService:

```
angular.module('wp.source')
.factory('SourceService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getSources: function () {
            var model = {
                sources: []
            };
            var promises = [];
            return $http.get('datasets/project.json')
                .then(function (data) {
                    if(localStorage['files'] != null) {
                        var files = JSON.parse(localStorage['files']);
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            model.sources.push(files[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    var sources = [];
                    for (var sourceId in data.data.sources) {
                        var source = data.data.sources[sourceId];
                        source.id = sourceId;
                        sources.push(source);
                    }


                    angular.forEach(sources, function (source) {
                        promises.push($http.get('datasets/' + source.filename).then(function (datasource, resolve) {
                            var metadata = datasource.data.metadata;
                            var source = {
                                name: metadata.name,
                                address: metadata.url,
                                frequency: metadata.refresh,
                                type: metadata.type,
                                tags: metadata.tags,
                                size: metadata.size,
                                active: source.active,
                                sourceID: source.id,
                                sourceFile: source.filename
                            };
                            return source;
                        }));
                    });

                    //var finalPromise = sources.reduce(function (promise, source, index, array) {
                    //    return promise.then(function (a) {
                    //        var query = $http.get('datasets/' + source.filename)
                    //            .then(function (datasource) {
                    //                var metadata = datasource.data.metadata;
                    //                model.sources.push({
                    //                    name: metadata.name,
                    //                    address: metadata.url,
                    //                    frequency: metadata.refresh,
                    //                    type: metadata.type,
                    //                    tags: metadata.tags,
                    //                    size: metadata.size,
                    //                    active: source.active,
                    //                    sourceID: source.id,
                    //                    sourceFile: source.filename
                    //                });
                    //            });
                    //    });
                    //}, $q.when([]));
                    //
                    //finalPromise.finally(function () {
                    //    return model;
                    //})
                    $q.all(function () {
                        return model;
                    });
                });

        }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('wp.source')
.controller('InventoryCtrl', function ($scope, orders, sources) {
    $scope.orders = orders.data;

    $scope.gridView = true;
    $scope.rowView = false;

    $scope.allSources = sources.sources;
    $scope.shownSources = $scope.allSources;
...
```

Currently I have the problem that the value is injected before "model" is fully loaded. I tried to pack the subqueries into a $q.all promise, but I don't know exactly where to go from there

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use $q.defer() and returned the deferred promise object. 
You code will look something like this.

```
angular.module('wp.source')
.factory('SourceService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getSources: function () {
            var model = {
                sources: []
            };
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            var promises = [];
            return $http.get('datasets/project.json')
                .then(function (data) {
                    if(localStorage['files'] != null) {
                        var files = JSON.parse(localStorage['files']);
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            model.sources.push(files[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    var sources = [];
                    for (var sourceId in data.data.sources) {
                        var source = data.data.sources[sourceId];
                        source.id = sourceId;
                        sources.push(source);
                    }


                    angular.forEach(sources, function (source) {
                        promises.push($http.get('datasets/' + source.filename).then(function (datasource, resolve) {
                            var metadata = datasource.data.metadata;
                            var source = {
                                name: metadata.name,
                                address: metadata.url,
                                frequency: metadata.refresh,
                                type: metadata.type,
                                tags: metadata.tags,
                                size: metadata.size,
                                active: source.active,
                                sourceID: source.id,
                                sourceFile: source.filename
                            };
                            return source;
                        }));
                    });

                    //var finalPromise = sources.reduce(function (promise, source, index, array) {
                    //    return promise.then(function (a) {
                    //        var query = $http.get('datasets/' + source.filename)
                    //            .then(function (datasource) {
                    //                var metadata = datasource.data.metadata;
                    //                model.sources.push({
                    //                    name: metadata.name,
                    //                    address: metadata.url,
                    //                    frequency: metadata.refresh,
                    //                    type: metadata.type,
                    //                    tags: metadata.tags,
                    //                    size: metadata.size,
                    //                    active: source.active,
                    //                    sourceID: source.id,
                    //                    sourceFile: source.filename
                    //                });
                    //            });
                    //    });
                    //}, $q.when([]));
                    //
                    //finalPromise.finally(function () {
                    //    return model;
                    //})
                    $q.all(promises).then(function () {
                        deferred.resolve(model);
                    });
                });
        }
          return deferred.promise();
    }
});
```

**EDIT** As others have mentioned you need to pass your array of promises into $q.all to get this to work right. Also it's worth noting that $q.all will return an array with the results of each promise in the order they were in the promise array.

[Here's a plunker demoing the use of defer](http://plnkr.co/edit/jY7Mbo8en00EizyzPdDr?p=preview).

There's more $q.defer and $q.all here in the [Angular's Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: You're welcome! If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer that would be awesome.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot! Thx for the help again!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `$q.all` with array of promises and return it from outer promise:

```
angular.module('wp.source')
.factory('SourceService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getSources: function() {
            var model = {
                sources: []
            };
            return $http.get('datasets/project.json').then(function(data) {

                if (localStorage['files'] != null) {
                    var files = JSON.parse(localStorage['files']);
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        model.sources.push(files[i]);
                    }
                }

                var sources = [],
                    promises = [];

                for (var sourceId in data.data.sources) {
                    var source = data.data.sources[sourceId];
                    source.id = sourceId;
                    sources.push(source);
                }

                var promises = sources.map(function(source) {
                    return $http.get('datasets/' + source.filename).then(function(datasource, resolve) {
                        var metadata = datasource.data.metadata;
                        model.sources.push({
                            name: metadata.name,
                            address: metadata.url,
                            frequency: metadata.refresh,
                            type: metadata.type,
                            tags: metadata.tags,
                            size: metadata.size,
                            active: source.active,
                            sourceID: source.id,
                            sourceFile: source.filename
                        });
                    });    
                });

                return $q.all(promises).then(function() {
                    return model;
                });
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `$q.all` correctly. The simplest possible fix to your code would be changing

```
$q.all(function () {
    return model;
});
```

to

```
$q.all(promises).then(function() {
    return model;
});
```

You're basically not "telling" `$q.all` which promises it needs to aggregate. Please refer to the [documentation for $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and check how `all` works.